# How to change the Yahoo Mail, sign out URL?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, yahoo

This is my code I came up with (w/ lots of outside help; I'm not fluent in JS):

```
setTimeout(function() {
   var logout = document.querySelector('a.yucs-signout'),
   link = "http://login.yahoo.com/config/login?logout=1&.src=cdgm&.intl=us&.direct=2&.done=http://ma
il.yahoo.com";
   logout.setAttribute ('onclick', 'location.href = 
\"' + link + '\"');
   logout.setAttribute ('href', link);
}, 17000)
```

I'm trying to change the sign-out URL at Yahoo Mail, when clicking the "Sign Out" dropdown menu item, so that you are redirected back to the Yahoo Mail login page -- not the yahoo.com "main page".  This is to make it easier to login with another account.

We couldn't get it to work. Even added a timeout to the code in case my js was running too soon. Still no go.

I was told "The class="yucs-submenu-toggle" on the `<a id="yucs-menu_link_profile">` with no CSS on :hover means javascript is being used."

Logout control screenshot:
[image: Logout control screenshot]

You have to hover over that section to get the menu to dropdown & see **Sign Out**.

I also made sure my "Included page" was https: `https://*.mail.yahoo.*/*`

I'm trying to use this with Greasemonkey, why isn't it working?

Edit: I was thinking [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552270/greasemonkey-script-for-changing-inbox-to-test-at-yahoo-mail/3554894#3554894) might have something useful, like the jQuery stuff in it?

Comment: Why do you need both the href and onclick attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the code in the question is copied verbatim, then it has syntax errors from improperly made, multi-line strings.
2. Don't set `onclick` from a userscript.  Ever!  In this case, no form of click event handling is necessary anyway, and may block the logout operation of the page.

Other than that, that code works for me -- at least on Yahoo, UK, mail.

Some more minor points:

1. You don't need a setTimeout in this case.
2. Don't brute-force the link like that; it may not always work.  Use regex to surgically change just the `done` variable part.

Here's **a complete working script**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Fix Yahoo mail logout
// @include     http://mail.yahoo.com/*
// @include     http://*.mail.yahoo.com/*
// @include     https://mail.yahoo.com/*
// @include     https://*.mail.yahoo.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

//-- Only run in the top page, not the various iframes.
if (window.self === window.top) {
    var logout = document.querySelector ('a.yucs-signout');
    if (logout) {
        var link = logout.href.replace (
            /&\.done=[^&#]+(&?)/, "&.done=http://mail.yahoo.com$1"
        );
        logout.href = link;
    }
    else
        console.error ("From GM script:  Node 'a.yucs-signout' not found.");
}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! From whatever future universe you're from, I bow down to your infinite JS + Regex wisdom. Live long and prosper. \\//